# Ubuntu shows recorded dvd as blank

Tags: 12.04, dvd, brasero

I recorded a music DVD in DVD player. The DVD is working well, but now I can't see the contents of the DVD on Ubuntu, it shows it as blank DVD.

Any idea how I can view the files?

Comment: Did you finalize the disc?

Comment: yes i finalized disc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of restricted software. DVD playback is not included in Ubuntu by default, because it is copyright protected.

From the softwarecenter install Ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: i installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` when i installed ubuntu.